# Is it possible to output google search results in IBM Watson Chatbot?

Tags: ibm-cloud, facebook-apps, ibm-watson, watson-conversation

I have created a chatbot with IBM Watson Assistant. But currently I have hardcoded all values in the dialog
e.g : When some user will ask "***Who created Computer ?***" then in the dialog flow I have written "***XYZ created computer***".

But suppose the user will ask about some other person and that value is not hardcoded in the dialogs on IBM Watson Assistant then is there any way by which I can provide Google search results?

Answer (score 1):

You can [make programmatic calls from within IBM Watson Assistant dialog nodes](https://console.bluemix.net/docs/services/conversation/dialog-actions.html#dialog-actions). Both server-side actions (IBM Cloud Functions) or client side calls (within the app) are supported. That way you can react to such queries as described and could call a search engine, database or somethin else.

This [IBM Cloud solution tutorial on how to build a database-driven Slackbot](https://console.bluemix.net/docs/tutorials/slack-chatbot-database-watson.html#build-a-database-driven-slackbot) uses server side actions to interact with a Db2 database. Instead of calling out to a database to fetch data, in your example, you would open a request to Google search.

I saw that you tagged it "facebook-apps". If you use [Botkit middleware](https://github.com/watson-developer-cloud/botkit-middleware) to build an integration with Facebook Messenger, then check out this [blog on how to enable actions in the Botkit Middleware for Watson Assistant](https://blog.4loeser.net/2018/06/enable-botkit-middleware-for-watson.html).

Comment: Yeah..I already deployed my chatbot using botkit-middleware on facebook messenger which is working fine.